# Yandex search selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Как из яндекса вытащить подсказки при вводе?
Например [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попыталась так:

```
  searchText_yandex = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@action='https://yandex.ru/search/' and @role='search']//div[@class='search2__input']")))  
for item in searchText_yandex :                                                                                                                                                                                     
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подсказки находятся в элементах `<span class="suggest2-item__text">`. Можно ввести текст запроса и искать эти элементы в DOM.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get("https://yandex.ru")

# Вводим текст в поле для поиска
driver.find_element_by_id('text').send_keys('тест')

# Ищем элементы <span class="suggest2-item__text">
suggestions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('suggest2-item__text')

for suggestion in suggestions:
    print(suggestion.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!